# omitting "public" from URL using .htaccess rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a current REST API where URL's used to look like following:

```
example.com/public/products
example.com/public/products/123
```

I have updated the URL structure to:

```
example.com/products
example.com/products/123
```

The issue is that there are current users of this REST API that only connect to the 'public' URL, so this update will give them 404 error. How can I add a rule to my rewrite so GET requests to URL with "public" get processed without "public" correctly.

```
example.com/public/products -> example.com/products
example.com/public/products/123 -> example.com/products/123
```

How can I write a rewrite rule that does this for me?

Answer (score 0):

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

You can test it here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

---

**Regular Expression:**

`^`
Matches beginning of string (the URL path in this case).

`public/`
Matches the string "public/".

`(.*)`
Parentheses make this a capturing group; `.` matches any character except line breaks; `*` matches zero or more of preceding token.

`$`
Matches end of string.

---

**Output URL (with capture group reference numbers):**

`$1`: Insert the contents of capture group #1

---

**Options:**

`[R=301,L]`: Performs a [301 [R]edirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) and indicates this is the [L]ast rule thus stopping the rewriting process immediately .

---

Apache Module mod_rewrite documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried that rule..it takes me to http://example.com/apache/example.com/web/public/products which is the server path of the application. Did not work ..

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>  that is my .htaccess file, wish they allowed formattting on commments.